# Android Lint: how to ignore missing translation warnings in a regional locale string file that purposely only overrides some default translations?

Tags: android, localization, translation, lint, android-lint

Is it possible to translate some strings, but not all, in a separate resource file without Lint complaining about **MissingTranslation**?

For example: my app's strings are all in **res/values/strings.xml**.  One of the strings is

`<string name="postal_code">Postal Code</string>`

Since "postal code" is usually called "zip code" in the US, I want to add another resource **res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml** with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="postal_code">Zip Code</string>
</resources>
```

However, Lint complains about other strings in **values/strings.xml** but not in **values-en-rUS/strings.xml**

I realize you can suppress the warnings by specifying `tools:ignore` in **values/strings.xml**.  But this is undesirable because the Lint warning is actually useful when translating to another language.

Instead, is it possible to suppress the warning in the **values-en-rUS/strings.xml** file, as in, telling Lint not to use that file as criteria when looking for missing translations?

Comment: Related/almost a dupe: [Ignoring Android Lint “MissingTranslation” check for partial translations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019282/ignoring-android-lint-missingtranslation-check-for-partial-translations)

Comment: Please mark @blahdiblah answer as accepted, because it is actually a correct answer.

Answer (score 71):

A nice way to disable MissingTranslations check is to add the option in module specific `build.gradle` file .

```
android {

    lintOptions{
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    //other build tags
}
```

If the strings are not present in locale specific Strings file, it will take the strings from the default file which generally is `strings.xml`.

Comment: Note that this will disable *all* MissingTranslation warning/errors, so you won't get false positives for `en-rUS` intentionally partially overriding `en` defaults, but you also won't get true positives when some other locale is missing a translation.

Comment: I definitely found your answer useful, however, it could be that you're interested in ignoring translations in different levels (ignore them all, ignore only strings in a given file or ignore only one string). Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53206467/973919

Answer (score 41):

I found a better solution according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13797364/190309

Just add `ignore="MissingTranslation"` to your `string.xml`, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:ignore="MissingTranslation" >

  <!-- your strings here; no need now for the translatable attribute -->

</resources>
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a solution that only ignores *some* missing translations. This solution applies to everything in a given file.

Answer (score 25):

Lint supports partial regional translations, but needs to know what language the default strings are.  That way, it can distinguish a partial regional translation from missing translations in a different locale.

To specify the locale in `values/strings.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="en">
```

Quote from the lint command-line tool, when running **`lint --show`**:

```
By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide a
subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language strings. [...]

You can tell lint (and other tools) which language is the default language
in your res/values/ folder by specifying tools:locale="languageCode" for
the root <resources> element in your resource file. (The tools prefix
refers to the namespace declaration http://schemas.android.com/tools.)
```

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/TranslationDetector.java#88

Add the locale specification to your default language file, and you shouldn't get that error for `en-rUS`, but will still be informed of any other missing translations.

Comment: your answer make sense but it does not work with me 
- I have a default strings file "values/strings.xml" and I translate some of the strings to en-rGB I put them in "values-en-rUS/strings.xml" file 
- I added tools:locale="en" to "values/strings.xml" but still got error that some strings is not translated to "en"

Comment: I try this and actually it works. If you run a lint task, after adding tools:locale="en", MissingTranslation warnings won't appear.
But in Android Studio 3.5.1, red lines will still be there. So it's probably an Android Studio bug.
This answer should be marked as the right answer

Comment: I have created a ticket to Google : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142590628

Comment: @michgauz I saw you kept on the google guys to make this fix even when they didn't want to, good on you and thank you!

Answer (score 16):

This seems to not answered yet, so I show you one solution:

In your DEFAULT xml file, you can define strings, that don't need translations like following:

```
<string name="developer" translatable="false">Developer Name</string>
```

This string does not need to be translated and lint will not complain about it either...

Comment: This will switch the problem to warnings about translating untranslatable strings in the locales that are supposed to provide a different resource.

Answer (score 16):

This is a Swiss knife answer, so you can ignore the missing translations message depending on which situation you are:

- Ignore all `MissingTranslation` message:

  Edit your `build.gradle` file:

  ```
  android {
      lintOptions{
          disable 'MissingTranslation'
      }
  }
  ```
- Ignore all `MissingTranslation` messages in a concrete `resources.xml` file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">

        <!-- your strings here; no need now for the translatable attribute -->

  </resources>
  ```
- Ignore `MissingTranslation` message for only one string:

  ```
  <string name="developer" translatable="false">Developer Name</string>
  ```

Comment: Three ways to handle missingTranslation warning

Answer (score 1):

In case of Android Gradle plugin 7.4.x, and .kts:

```
android {
  lint {
    disable.add("MissingTranslation")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, please look at the toolbar buttons of the Lint warnings view. One of them is called "Ignore in file". This should help, but only if Lint assigns the error to your "US" file. That button simply modifies the lint.xml file in your project, so you can investigate (and undo) that easily.

More details about that file specific suppression are at http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

Answer (score 0):

For the lint configuration file `lint.xml`:

```
<issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="ignore" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If case of using **gradle 7** :

```
lint {
        disable("MissingTranslation")
    }
```